# How to mention colors in a figure?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Which of the followings is correct and more natural?

- ... the samples of these classes are shown in red and blue respectively.
- ... the samples of these classes are shown with red and blue respectively.
- ... the samples of these classes are shown as red and blue respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on **how the samples are marked!**

We use *marked in* if the whole thing is in red and blue.

[image]

We use *marked with* if the thing is in red/blue fonts/letters.

[image]

*Shown as blue/red* misleads me that the samples are the color themselves!

**After the OP's edit and adding the image**

In this case, as Tyler says, all are okay. However, I'd prefer that you mention them not merely as colors but colors and **dots**. Having said that, *"..... the samples of these classes are shown as red and blue **dots (or whatever)** respectively.* This'll make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, and I just edited my post to clarify it, please note.

Comment: I would not say "This text is marked with red." I would say "This text is displayed in red." (Or, "...uses a red font."  The color of the text is generally not a "marking".) Moreover, in the first diagram, I would say, "Some of this text is **highlighted** in red and yellow."

Comment: @J.R. no no... what you say is correct but I wrote it personally on MS Word and wanted to say that *this is how the text is marked **with** red.* It has become interesting though.

Comment: When I hear "This is marked with red," I would generally picture something like [this](http://www.torchlightdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/scrivener1.jpg).

Comment: @J.R. I know a bit of HTML programming, *mark* means *highlight*. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/mark.html Also, check out, if you *mark background* it's *highlighting*. In other words, when the text is marked *in*, it's the **area** and when the text is marked *with*, it's the font color or some symbol. We use this everyday in IT. This is understood better having Excel sheet in mind. The cells marked IN red and the fonts marked WITH red (color).

Comment: @MaulikV - I'll grant you that there are some contexts where the word _mark_ may be used in the way you say. That said, I don't believe the O.P.'s question is one of them. Moreover, outside those contexts, the word is likely to be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to paint colour, the first sentence is the most acceptable. 
When talking about colours "in" is the preposition most used. Do you remember " The woman in red"?